# Retrieve current active screen name Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, navigation, screen

My application is a tab based one. For example, app has got 3 tabs -  A, B & C. If the currently opened tab is "A", when the user again tries to click on the same tab, app shouldn't do anything.

I tried to do this using the following code snippet

```
final Screen currentActiveScreen = UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen();

        if (newScreen == currentActiveScreen)
        {
            return;
        }
```

New screen is the screen that the user is trying to navigate to.

But this code is not firing and when I tried to debug, I found that some random number is also coming with the screen and hence the code is not entering the if loop.

The values in the condition comes like this and is returning false. 
AScreen@497293b7 == AScreen@2f25c01e

So, Is there anything wrong in what I'm trying to do ? How can we get the screen name only.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such thing as a screen name in BlackBerry Java. And Kevin is right - you cannot compare the screens directly (for the reasons explained in his reply). You need to define your own discerning mechanism to check the **type** of the screen you would navigate to before even creating it.

If you have 3 tabs, you can pre-create 3 screens (one per tab), store them in three members of your Object, then simply remove and add the needed screen when the user presses something. Before doing that, you can indeed compare the screen you are trying to bring up with the current one.

Something like this:

```
Screen tabA = new MyScreenForTabA();
Screen tabB = new MyScreenForTabB();
Screen tabC = new MyScreenForTabC();
//...
// Somewhere else in the code
//...
    Screen nextScreen;
    switch (chosenTabLetter) { // Just throwing an idea
        case 'A':
            nextScreen = tabA;
            break;
        case 'B':
            nextScreen = tabB;
            break;
        case 'C':
            nextScreen = tabC;
            break;
    }
    if (nextScreen == currentScreen) {
        return;
    }
```

This way you can juggle the three screens without constantly creating new ones.

Answer (score 0):

There's not much to go on here, you may need to add more detail.

Those numbers you're seeing are the hashcodes of the objects. If `newScreen` refers to a new instance of a screen, `==` wont evaluate to true.
There are 2 choices that come to mind,
either override the `equals` method of your custom screen;
 or make A,B, and C different classes (they most likely are already), then use `instanceof`

eg.

```
ScreenA newScreen = new ScreenA();
if (currentActiveScreen instanceof ScreenA) return;
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Will try this out.

B/w, is there any way we can find out the screen names ??

Comment: What do you mean by screen name?

Comment: title of the screen !!

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure. Since there isn't a method for it, I'd just override the `setTitle` method and save it myself. Then make a getter.